# MusicXML <instrument id="BLAH"> not affecting MIDI or playback

Tags: midi, file-conversion, musicxml, soundfont

EDIT: Added complete example at the bottom, for testing (non-working, small but complete).

At the top of a MusicXML file, you can define MIDI instruments with IDs, Channel, and Program information as follows (see this [w3.org page for a full example](https://www.w3.org/2021/06/musicxml40/musicxml-reference/examples/tutorial-percussion/))

```
<midi-instrument id="Piano">
    <midi-channel>1</midi-channel>
    <midi-program>1</midi-program>
</midi-instrument>

<midi-instrument id="Harp">
    <midi-channel>2</midi-channel>
    <midi-program>2</midi-program>
</midi-instrument>
```

Then, later in the file, within a given `<note>` element, you can insert an `<instrument id="PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED_ID"/>` tag to switch to the defined MIDI channel and program (again, see example linked above for a complete copy-and-paste MRE) as follows:

```
 <note default-x="250">
  <pitch>
    <step>C</step>
    <octave>4</octave>
  </pitch>
  <duration>4</duration>
  <instrument id="piano"/>
  <voice>1</voice>
  <type>16th</type>
  <stem>up</stem>
  <staff>1</staff>
</note>

<note default-x="250">
  <pitch>
    <step>D</step>
    <octave>4</octave>
  </pitch>
  <duration>4</duration>
  <instrument id="harp"/>
  <voice>1</voice>
  <type>16th</type>
  <stem>up</stem>
  <staff>1</staff>
</note>
```

**However, when I create a file following the syntax above, and I open it in a MusicXML compatible program (e.g. Musescore or Reaper), the `<instrument id="BLAH/>` has no effect on the MIDI channel or program**  Theoretically, the example given above should change from the defined "piano" to the defined "harp".

I am using a soundfont that does include channel and program information, so I don't think it's that.  Furthermore, inspecting the MIDI data generated by converting or exporting the MusicXML file as MIDI shows no changes to the program or channel parameters.

**I'm not sure whether this is a (1) syntax error on my part, (2) an interpretation error by the MusicXML readers (but I've tried multiple programs), or (3)...?**

Thanks!

**Minimal Reproducible Example for testing:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE score-partwise PUBLIC "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 3.0 Partwise//EN" "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
<score-partwise version="3.0">
  <identification>
    <encoding>
      <software>REAPER 6.25/OSX64</software>
      <encoding-date>2021-08-08</encoding-date>
    </encoding>
  </identification>
  <defaults>
    <scaling>
      <millimeters>7</millimeters>
      <tenths>40</tenths>
    </scaling>
  </defaults>

  <part-list>
    <score-part id="P1">

      <part-name>Track 1</part-name>
      <score-instrument id="piano">
        <instrument-name>piano</instrument-name>
      </score-instrument>
      <score-instrument id="harp">
        <instrument-name>harp</instrument-name>
      </score-instrument>
      <score-instrument id="flute">
        <instrument-name>flute</instrument-name>
      </score-instrument>

      <midi-instrument id="piano">
        <midi-channel>1</midi-channel>
        <midi-program>1</midi-program>
      </midi-instrument>
      <midi-instrument id="harp">
        <midi-channel>2</midi-channel>
        <midi-program>2</midi-program>
      </midi-instrument>
      <midi-instrument id="flute">
        <midi-channel>3</midi-channel>
        <midi-program>3</midi-program>
      </midi-instrument>

    </score-part>
  </part-list>

  <part id="P1">
    <measure number="1" width="540">
      <attributes>
        <divisions>16</divisions>
        <key>
          <fifths>0</fifths>
        </key>
        <time>
          <beats>4</beats>
          <beat-type>4</beat-type>
        </time>
        <staves>2</staves>
        <clef number="1">
          <sign>G</sign>
          <line>2</line>
        </clef>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>F</sign>
          <line>4</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
      <direction placement="above">
        <direction-type>
          <metronome halign="left">
            <beat-unit>quarter</beat-unit>
            <per-minute>120</per-minute>
          </metronome>
        </direction-type>
        <sound tempo="120"/>
      </direction>
      <note default-x="120">
        <rest/>
        <duration>32</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>half</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
            <note default-x="250">
                <pitch>
                    <step>C</step>
                    <octave>4</octave>
                </pitch>
                <duration>4</duration>
                <instrument id="flute"/>
                <voice>1</voice>
                <type>16th</type>
                <stem>up</stem>
                <staff>1</staff>
            </note>
      <note default-x="280">
        <rest/>
        <duration>4</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>16th</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <note default-x="330">
        <rest/>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>eighth</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <note default-x="380">
        <pitch>
          <step>D</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <instrument id="piano"/>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>eighth</type>
        <stem>up</stem>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <note default-x="450">
        <rest/>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>eighth</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <backup>
        <duration>64</duration>
      </backup>
      <note default-x="250">
        <rest/>
        <duration>64</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>whole</type>
        <staff>2</staff>
      </note>
    </measure>
    <measure number="2" width="480">
      <note default-x="60">
        <rest/>
        <duration>4</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>16th</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <note default-x="110">
        <pitch>
          <step>E</step>
          <alter>-1</alter>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <instrument id="harp"/>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>eighth</type>
        <stem>up</stem>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <note default-x="170">
        <rest/>
        <duration>4</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>16th</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <note default-x="220">
        <rest/>
        <duration>16</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <note default-x="380">
        <rest/>
        <duration>32</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>half</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <backup>
        <duration>64</duration>
      </backup>
      <note default-x="320">
        <rest/>
        <duration>64</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>whole</type>
        <staff>2</staff>
      </note>
    </measure>
    <measure number="3" width="480">
      <note default-x="250">
        <rest/>
        <duration>64</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>whole</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <backup>
        <duration>64</duration>
      </backup>
      <note default-x="250">
        <rest/>
        <duration>64</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>whole</type>
        <staff>2</staff>
      </note>
    </measure>
    <measure number="4" width="480">
      <note default-x="250">
        <rest/>
        <duration>64</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>whole</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </note>
      <backup>
        <duration>64</duration>
      </backup>
      <note default-x="250">
        <rest/>
        <duration>64</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>whole</type>
        <staff>2</staff>
      </note>
    </measure>
  </part>
</score-partwise>
```

Comment: I guess we would need to see the rest of your XML file to know if these (valid-looking) elements are in their correct places. But maybe you should run your XML through a validator that can use the XSD for MusicXML, rather than trust our eyes.

Comment: @Noah I've added an MRE at the bottom of the file, per your first suggestion.  I also ran the document above through an online validator, and it passed.  I'm not familiar with XSD, so it's possible that the "pass" isn't to be trusted, however.